# Mongoose Validation Error occurs on OpenShift but not local version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I am migrating my Node.js server with Mongoose to OpenShift and an error occurs on the live server that I cannot reproduce on my local WebStorm built-in server.

I get the error message:

```
undefined: {
    properties: {
    message: "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"
    type: "cast"
}-
message: "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"
name: "ValidatorError"
kind: "cast"
}
```

This occurs when I try to push an element into the `items` array and save, for the following schema:

```
var listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  items: [
    {
      name:{
        type: String,
        required:true
      },
      quantity:Number,
      check: Boolean
    }
  ]
});
```

The local version that works, and the OpenShift version use the exact same code.  The code that adds the new element is:

```
var listId = req.params["id"];

if (sessions.verifyToken(userId, token)) {
    var data = req.body;

    var query = List.findOne({
      owner: userId,
      "_id": listId
    });

    query.exec(function(err, list) {

...
//handle error and null (omitted for brevity)
...

    list.items.push({ // error thrown here
        name: req.body["name"],
        quantity: req.body["quantity"],
        check: false
    });

    list.save(function(err, list) {
        if (err) {
            var message = "Unable save appended list to persistent memory";
            console.log(message, err);
            res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            res.send(JSON.stringify({success: false, message: message, error: err}));
            return;
        }

        res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
    });
});
```

I thought that maybe an earlier version of the schema had added a constraint, so I dropped the `lists` collection, but the problem did not go away.

What might be different on the OpenShift PaaS that could be causing the error?

[Edit]
Just for fun, I removed all required fields from `items` and now the error message is this:

```
"undefined": {
    "properties": {
        "message": "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined",
        "type": "cast"
    },
    "message": "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined",
    "name": "ValidatorError",
    "kind": "cast"
},
"owner": {
    "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "owner"
    },
    "message": "Path `owner` is required.",
    "name": "ValidatorError",
    "kind": "required",
    "path": "owner"
}
```

This seems to suggest that the Model loses its `owner` field somewhere between finding the list and saving it again.
[/Edit]

Comment: which line is throwing? is the mongodb api (interface) same local & OpenShift?

Comment: the call to `list.save` is throwing the error. Hmm, I think I'm running v3 and it looks like OpenShift runs 2.4. I'll regress my version and see if it breaks

Comment: hmm, even when I'm using MongoDb2.4 on my local, it still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OpenShift, when you `find` or `findOne` a model that has a required reference to another entity, that field will not be automatically filled in. Thus, when `save` is called, the field will be missing. Change

```
var query = List.findOne({
  owner: userId,
  "_id": listId
});
```

to

```
var query = List.findOne({
  owner: userId,
  "_id": listId
}).populate("owner");
```

For some reason, this does not work the same in every environment. For some, either it does automatically populate the reference field, or it assumed it unchanged when saving. I'm not sure which.